# Exception has occurred.MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getResourceUsage on channel resource_monitor)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-apk, resource-monitor

MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getResourceUsage on channel resource_monitor)).

The exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getResourceUsage on channel resource_monitor))